# Can't move uploaded file

Tags: php, image

I know this has been asked a lot, but I looked at all the solutions to the other questions, and none of them worked.

I'm basically just using this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
```

with an image coming in from a POST request. The POST request is working fine though.

What I've tried: `CHMOD -R 755` and `CHMOD -R 777` (which have been the answers to SO many other questions I've seen so far), but they don't change the error:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/myImage.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Users/Sites/r/add.php on line 16

Comment: @MarceloRodovalho According to the path it is a Unix based operating system.

Comment: Does the folder `uploads` exist?

Comment: @MarceloRodovalho, I'm on Mac OSX with an apache server

Comment: Really, sorry. I asked, because I had the same problem using IIS, and the problem was the users permissions in Windows. Cant solve, so I needed to change the path of temp folder.

Comment: Can you try echoing $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"] ?

Comment: @WillyPt Sure: `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpGixDfX`

Answer (score 0):

The german PHP.net states:

> If safe mode is activated, PHP checks if the files/directories have the same UID (owner) as the script itself.

Source: http://php.net/manual/de/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Also, have you set `chmod 777` on the `temp` folder as well as on the target folder?

Comment: Haha I commented about that, luckily, it's not a stupid mistake. You can check if PHP is running in safemode with `ini_get('safe_mode')`.

Comment: @Adam, I just set the temp folder to CHMOD 777 but still the same problem?

Comment: Can you try to specify the relative path more, e.g. if your `/uploads/` is in `/Users/Sites/r/uploads/` replace `"uploads/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]` with `"./uploads/" . $_FILES["photo"]["name"]`? If that does not work, too, please cd to `/Users/Sites/r/` in the terminal, type `ls -la` and post the output.